# How to change the default font size of Java swing components

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt, uimanager

When doing Java JFrame design, I need to edit the font size and font type manually each time drag and drop from the Swing palette. The default font of Java Swing components is Tahoma 11 plain.

What I want is the font size and font type to be set to Tahoma 15 plain when I drag `JTextfield` and then `JLabel`. So I don’t need to change manually anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjusting the `UIDefaults` is one way.  Another is to [design a pluggable look & feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a netbeans platform problem. Use the UIManager class to set the Font for the whole program. Hope these links will help you.

[Setting the Default Font of Swing Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434845/setting-the-default-font-of-swing-program-in-java)

[Setting the Global Font for a Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824342/setting-the-global-font-for-a-java-application)

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late